# How to change the background-color of an element that is inside a GatsbyJS component, based on the page where I import the component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

It's the first time I'm building a website with GatsbyJS and I'm trying to build some components to use all over the site.

One of these components is the footer. I wrote its structure but I want to change the color of a `<div>` that is part of the footer based on which page am I visiting. I don't want the whole footer to change color, only this div that is part of the footer.

To be more accurate: if I'm visiting the Homepage I want this div to have an orange Background whereas if I'm inside the contact page I want it to have a blue background.

Is it possible?

This is part of the code of my footer (that is the footer.js gatsby component that I import in my pages):

```html
<footer className={footerStyle.footer}>
  <div className={footerStyle.parteSopra}>
    <div className={footerStyle.parteSopra}>
      <div className={footerStyle.ottanta}>
        <h3 className={footerStyle.rimaniamo+ ' '+footerStyle.dimTitoli}>rimaniamo<br />in contatto</h3>
      </div>
      <div className={footerStyle.venti}>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div className={footerStyle.parteSotto}>
      <div className={footerStyle.ottanta+ ' '+footerStyle.boxFrecciaBlu}>
        <div className={footerStyle.contieniFrecciaBlu}>
          <img className={footerStyle.frecciaBlu} src={frecciaBlu} alt="Freccia giù" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={footerStyle.venti+ ' '+footerStyle.boxFbEInstaBlu}>
        <div className={footerStyle.contieniFbBlu}>
          <a href="https://it-it.facebook.com/DiamanteCalzature" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <img className={footerStyle.fbBlu} src={iconaFbBlu} alt="Facebook" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className={footerStyle.contieniInstaBlu}>
          <a href="https://instagram.com/diamantecalzature?igshid=cta3uh8iob7a" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <img className={footerStyle.instaBlu} src={iconaInstaBlu} alt="Instagram" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="coloreFootSotto" className={footerStyle.parteSotto+ ' '+footerStyle.coloreFooterSotto}>
    <div className={footerStyle.ottanta}>

    </div>
    <div className={footerStyle.venti+ ' '+footerStyle.boxTornaSu}>

    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I import it in my pages writing `<Footer />` and I thought I could add an attribute, a prop, or something inside that tag to realize what I want. I need the div with Id `id="coloreFootSotto"` to have a different background-color based on the page I am visiting. At the moment I'm just manipulating the DOM in some pages to change the background-color but I was wondering if it is possible to do it with props or something like that (maybe not).

Does anyone know it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gatsby uses reach router](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reach-router-and-gatsby/) so you can use [useLocation](https://reach.tech/router/api/useLocation) in your component and do something with the `location.pathname` for specific routes.

```
// Footer.js
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from "@reach/router"

import Container from 'components/Container';

const Footer = () => {
  const {pathname} = useLocation()
  console.log(pathname)
  return (
    <footer style={pathname=== '/' ? {backgroundColor: 'blue'} : null} >
      <Container>
        <p>&copy; {new Date().getFullYear()}, My Gatsby Site</p>
      </Container>
    </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

It's also worth mentioning that [you can get location data from a gatsby page via its location prop](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/).

Depending on how your app is structured, you could also get this data from your page component, and pass the relevant data down via props down through your component tree.

eg IndexPage > Layout > Footer

For multiple pages, you could do something like this.

```
// Footer.js
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from "@reach/router"
import Container from 'components/Container';

const pagesWithColoredFooter = ['/', '/page-2', 'page-3'];

const Footer = () => {
  const {pathname} = useLocation()
  console.log(pathname)
  return (
    <footer style={pagesWithColoredFooter.includes(pathname) ? {backgroundColor: 'blue'} : null} >
      <Container>
        <p>&copy; {new Date().getFullYear()}, My Gatsby Site</p>
      </Container>
    </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
If I use this method that you said <footer style={pathname=== '/' ? {backgroundColor: 'blue'} : null} > how can I specify more than one page where I want the blue background?

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I'll try and I'll make you know if I made it work

Comment: Excuse me but I tried and probably I didn't completely understand how to use the array of paths, could you please make me a usage example with my or your code? Thank you

Comment: Great, thank you!
Sorry if I ask you another question about it: is it also possible to use this method to modify onOver effects (like onMouseOver="this.style.whatever" or something similar) or to change a used image with another one always based on the page?

Comment: So you only want to do that on certain pages?

Comment: `useLocation` from `@reach/router` returns the location to any component. With that information, you can do anything you need.

Comment: I managed to do everything in the end. Thank you so much again for the help